# Stored Procedure Error : call failed for: call procedureName(id,type)(1242) : subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
SELECT 
    p.PackageID, 
    PackageName,
    user_assigned_packages.PackagePrice,
    p.PackageType,
    Keywords,
    Credits,
    SMSIncomingCost,
    SMSOutgoingCost,
    MMSIncomingCost,
    MMSOutgoingCost,
    CreditType,
    p.LastModifiedDate,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    IF(p.CreatedBy = user_assigned_packages.UserID, true, false) as isowner  
FROM packages p
INNER JOIN users u on p.CreatedBy = u.UserID
INNER JOIN user_assigned_packages ON user_assigned_packages.PackageID = p.PackageID 
WHERE  (p.PackageType = PackageType or (PackageType = 0 )) AND user_assigned_packages.UserID = UserID
```

This is my stored procedure : With the help of this userid i need to find the parent_userid which is in tbl_users table,after finding parent_userid,i need to check isvisible colomn of the parent_userid which is in tbl_userassignedpackage table if the value is 1 the procedure should execute

Here i have added a piece of code to it at last line

AND (SELECT isvisibleforclients FROM user_assigned_packages
     WHERE (user_assigned_packages.UserID = 
    (SELECT ParentUserID FROM users WHERE users.UserID = UserID))) =1

It is working perfectly as i expected only for 1 row , if the result is more than one row it gives the above specified error ...Please help what i should do to solve this...
Thanks

Comment: Convert the WHERE+subselects to a JOIN+condition

Comment: can you please convert it? @AlexK.